# Suppress error from deSolve::lsoda

Tags: r, error-handling, ode, differential-equations

I'm running some algorithms that use approximate Bayesian computation (e.g. see Toni et al., 2009) and these require repeatedly solving the Lotka-Volterra system of equations with a randomly generated set of input parameters.  I'm using the `lsoda` function from the [`deSolve` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/index.html).

Occasionally this function throws an error and I was hoping to ignore this using the `try(..., silent = TRUE)` function although this doesn't seem to work (see example below).  Setting `options(show.error.messages = FALSE)` doesn't work either.

How do I suppress printing of the error message from deSolve::lsoda?

```
require(deSolve)

# Differential equations defining the system
LV <- function(Time, State, Pars){

    with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {

    dx <- a*x - x*y
    dy <- b*x*y - y

    return(list(c(dx, dy)))
    }
    )
}

# Parameters
pars <- c(a = 1.0, b = 1.0)

# Initial conditions
init <- c(x = 1.0, y = 0.5)

# Time steps
times <- seq(0, 15, length.out = 100)

problem_seeds <- c(7, 241, 361, 365, 468, 473, 649, 704, 724, 745, 838)

for (i in problem_seeds){
    set.seed(i)

    # Sample from pi(theta), prior for parameter vector (a, b)
    theta_star <- runif(2, -10, 10)
    names(theta_star) <- c("a", "b")

    # Simulate a dataset using these parameters (at the specified times)
    try(out <- lsoda(func = LV, 
            y = init, 
            parms = theta_star, 
            times = times), 
            silent = TRUE)
    dfs <- as.data.frame(out)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at page 44 of the vignette in `deSolve`, this kind of error is described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/deSolve.pdf).

You can solve this problem in reducing the absolute tolerance of the solution. In your example, the following approach works:

```
out <- lsoda(func = LV, 
             y = init, 
             parms = theta_star, 
             times = times,
             atol = 1e-3)
```

Note: your data.frame `dfs` will be overwritten in every loop and if you want the output of the problem_seeds in a data.frame, you can run a fuinction of the `apply` family. And you don't need the `try` function from now on.

Comment: That's a useful work-around.  Re: overwriting df - this is just a small part of the ABC algorithm (just to reproduce the issue), in the main algorithm the dataframe is used before being overwritten.  I will wait to see if anyone has thoughts on how to suppress the error.  Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: Have you read this? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2013q1/000164.html

Comment: I'd tried google and SO but not seen this one.  Thanks for sharing!  Seems like the issue is still present in 2016 after being posted in 2013.  Oh well, I'll try the work-around they suggest.  Thank you.